# Page 189 of which Werewolf Players Guide has "guidelines for cross-Gift learning"?

Tags: world-of-darkness, product-identification, books, werewolf-the-apocalypse

After long contemplation and because I lack access to the book and I don't know which I should track down second-hand, I ask the community:

Hengeyokai (WW 03063, published 1998) references on page 174 the following:

> Of course, the guidelines for cross-Gift learning given in the **Werewolf Players Guide (pg. 189)** should be followed fairly closely [...].

In  trying to figure out what is meant to be a Kitsune's benefit when learning gifts of other Breeds/Races/Auspieces – which according to the quote is detailed there – it is eluding me which version of the Werewolf players guide is meant: There are two: First and second edition, and sadly they share exactly the same name.

So which one is meant?! The old or the new?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reference is definitely accurate to the 2nd edition *Werewolf Player's Guide* - which features on page 189 a section titled "Trade Secrets" describing the guidelines for characters learning Gifts or rites from other Breeds. It's possible that the same rules are in the same place in the first edition of the guide - however, the [2nd edition *Werewolf Player's Guide*](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL8662941M/Werewolf_Players_Guide_A_Sourcebook_for_Werewolf_The_Apocalypse_(Werewolf_The_Apocalypse)) was published in April 1998, three months before [*Hengeyokai*](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL8662930M/Hengeyokai), published in  July of the same year - so assuming editors had their acts together, the 2nd edition of the guide was the current version at the time *Hengeyokai* was published so it seems most likely that was the intended reference.